# JavaScript String immutability

Tags: javascript

I was recently working on a [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/keyboard-row/description/) question and stumbled across something that I at first thought was strange, but then after looking at it for a second, realized it might have to do with JavaScript String immutability.

I wanted to ask and see what the community thought.

Here's a snippet of some code:

```js
var keys = function(words) {

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // With lower, ['hello', 'alaska', 'dad', 'peace']
    var lower = words[i].toLowerCase();
    console.log(`Word is ${lower}`);
  }

}

keys(['Hello', 'Alaska', 'Dad', 'Peace']);
```

Does `lower` work because since JS strings are immutable, we'd have to make a copy of the string first in order to use it elsewhere with the applied transformation (making the string lowercase)?

```js
var keys = function(words) {

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // Without lower, ['Hello', 'Alaska', 'Dad', 'Peace']
    words[i].toLowerCase();
    console.log(`Word is ${words[i]}`);
  }

}

keys(['Hello', 'Alaska', 'Dad', 'Peace']);
```

Does this not work because again, strings are immutable so a transformation cannot be applied?

Thanks

Comment: *"we'd have to make a copy of the string first in order to use it elsewhere with the applied transformation"* `toLowerCase()` simply returns a new string. You don't have to make a "copy" of the original string. Besides, since strings are immutable, doing a copy is a) not necessary and b) you wouldn't be able to tell whether you actually have a copy or not.

Comment: From the MDN `The toLowerCase() method returns the value of the string converted to lower case. toLowerCase() does not affect the value of the string str itself.` there's no  immutability issue here.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the difference between the first lower and second lower?

Comment: @Barmar I just updated the question :sweat-smile:

Comment: Still don't understand, all you did was remove the second `var` declaration, which is redundant because the variable is already declared.

Comment: It logs the same thing in both places.

Comment: @Barmar Should've been more clear. It should be interpreted as two separate pieces of code.

Comment: So the question is about the difference between assigning to a variable with `var lower =` and `lower =`?

Comment: The only difference is that the second one assigns to a global variable instead of declaring a local variable.

Comment: Third time is a charm :) @Barmar

Comment: When you say "without lower", I guess you mean "without var".

Comment: Have you noticed how dad's are special, even when forced to be lowercase they come out like -> `'Dad'` :)

Answer (score 3):

`toLowerCase()` doesn't modify the string it's called on. Since strings are immutable, it couldn't do so. But even if they were mutable, it's just not what the function is defined to do. It returns a *new* string containing the lowercase version of the original string.

It's analogous to the `slice()` method of arrays. Arrays are mutable, but `slice()` returns a new array containing the specified sub-array, it doesn't modify the original array (that's what `splice()` does).

So if you want to do anything with that new string, you need to assign it somewhere, pass it as an argument to a function, or call some other method on the result.

If you don't want the `lower` variable, you can write:

```
console.log(`Row is ${row[i].toLowerCase()}`);
```

Comment: @Keith I'm sure it's the old "downvote answers to poor questions" reason.

Comment: I also thought the OP made a good stab at asking too, if he doesn't understand something, isn't that why people are here to help :(  Anyway, I'm going to counter vote now. :).